# Gradle project import work in IDEA, but don't work in VS Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have this gradle java project with this **setting.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "${settings.ext.get("artifactory.contextUrl")}/example"
        credentials {
            username = 'myemail'
            password = 'mypassword'
        }
    }
}
```

When i import it into IDEA, everything works fine, but i want to import this project into VS Code, but when i try it, gradle build passed just like in IDEA, but it still shows many errors:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd1jj.png)
and java dont see imports [imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNuEh.png)

obviously it shouldn't be problem with project and config, but with vs code, cause like i said, IDEA import it normally, does any have idea?

I tried turn on nested projects in vs code gradle, but without change, really don't know where could be difference between IDEA and VSCODE gradle.

Comment: It may be a caching issue. Press ⌘ + ⇧ + P (Command + Shift + P) and select `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`.

Comment: Ye, i tried this already few times, but still without change

Answer (score 0):

Install the [**Gradle for Java**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) extension. Check to see if all dependencies are included.

[image]

For more information on using gradle in vscode see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_gradle).

Comment: This extension i already have, i looked to the dependencies like you show on photo and all my dependecies are included, so gradle is good, but i think vs code cant index or i dont know...